# how do i handle duplicate field error in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, backend

```
exports.createUser = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  // next(new Error("custom message"));
  const user = await User.create(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: { user },
  });
});
```

this is my function than I want to send error if there is a duplicate field that should be unique. It is wrapped with a catchAsyncError function that should handle all errors coming from this function.

```
exports.catchAsyncError = fn => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message);
      // console.log(err);
      next(err);
    });
  }; 
};
```

here is the catchAsyncError.

But for some reason when the email is already existing it doesn't send an error, it just hangs. But when I uncomment the second line on the createUser function it does send a response with the proper message, not the message defined in the second line.  can anyone help ??

I tried to debug it over and over again but it doesn't work.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'user name is required'],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'email is required'],
      unique: [true, 'email must be unique'],
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
    },
    questions: {
      type: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
      default: [],
    },
    answers: {
      type: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }],
    },
    reputation: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    followers: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        default: [],
      },
    ],
    followings: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        default: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

here is the user schema